# Angularjs, how to animate left/right movement on routeChange

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to animate an angular page left/right when changing routes.

The page should animate left if the user goes to a "deeper" level.
The page should animate right if the user goes to a "shallower" level.

This would give an app-feel (like Android/iOS).

I try to use the following method to program the level:

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate'] )
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home / cases page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'views/cases.html',
                controller  : 'CasesCtrl',
                controllerAs : 'vm',
                resolve: {
                    page: function() {
                        return {
                            level: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

            // route for the measurements page
            .when('/measurements/:route_id', {
                templateUrl : 'views/measurements.html',
                controller  : 'MeasurementsCtrl',
                controllerAs : 'vm',
                resolve: {
                    page: function() {
                        return {
                            level: 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

I try to use the level to set animation left/right in the main controller like this (not working):

```
function MainCtrl($rootScope, $route) {
    var vm = this;

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

        // this will show next with a "locals" property
        console.log('next', next);
        // this will show next without a "locals" property, showing that
        // "locals" is not yet available on routeChangeStart
        console.log('next extended', angular.extend({}, next));

        // set animation direction
        if (current == null) {
            // seems like this is the first page we open, so no animations needed
            vm.animateDirection = 'animate-not';
        } else if (!('page' in current.locals)) {
            // current.locals contains values set in the resolve part of $routeProvider
            vm.animateDirection = 'animate-not';
        } else if (!('page' in next.locals)) {
            // current.locals contains values set in the resolve part of $routeProvider
            vm.animateDirection = 'animate-not';
        } else if ('level' in vm) {
            if (current.locals.page.level > next.locals.page.level) {
                vm.animateDirection = 'animate-left-to-right'; // we go back a level, so animate from left to right
            } else {
                vm.animateDirection = 'animate-right-to-left'; // we go deeper, so animate from right to left
            }
        } else {
            vm.animateDirection = 'animate-not'; // first page, no animation
        }

    });

}
```

This gives me the error "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'page' in undefined", because the "locals" property is not yet defined during the "$routeChangeStart" event.

Is there a way to get the "level" of the different routes inside the $routeChangeStart event?

Kind regards,
Hendrik Jan

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access properties from `resolve` on `$routeChangeStart` because at this point, the route change could still be cancelled, so the resolve code hasn't been run yet.

That being said - you don't actually need to be using resolve here, because your values are hard coded. If you use the following approach to define the routes:

```
.when('/', {
  templateUrl : 'views/cases.html',
  controller  : 'CasesCtrl',
  controllerAs : 'vm',
  data: {
    level: 1
  }
})
```

You can then access then from your route change code very simply:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
  if(current.data.level < next.data.level) { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it seems "current" and "next" do not contain the properties from the when-method.

Comment: apologies - I just realised you're using the default angular router and not `ui.router`.

Comment: current only has the properties: $$route, loadedTemplateUrl, locals, params, pathParams, scope and __proto__. So there is no data inside current or next.

Comment: Ok, in this case I'm not sure - perhaps this isn't (simply) possible without using something like `ui.router`. I would strongly recommend that library at least until the bundled angular router is upgraded (soonish apparently).